# Selenium Webdriver doesn't maximize on MacOS environment

Tags: java, selenium

I am using chrome driver latest version 2.33 and exported the exact same code from windows to Mac but the browser is vertically half screen maximized, not maximizing fully. The same with Firefox.

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

But when I use fullscreen method it maximizes fully and bring the browser focus to foreground.
Is this a known issue or something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests in macOs Sierra 10.12.6, Selenium 3.6.0, and also with the latest release 3.5.3, with:

Firefox

- the current latest version of Firefox 56.0 (64 bit)
- v0.19.0 Geckodriver

Chrome:

- the current latest version of Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- chromeDriver 2.33

About Chrome, from [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)  seems that the problem had to be only in the  62+ version:

> Fixes a bug which caused Resizing/Positioning Window commands to fail
>   on Chrome 62+.

But I have your same problem (I tried also with the 2.32 Chrome Driver).

Regarding Firefox I made the following tests:

**1 test:**

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

In this case the window start maximized.

**2 test:**

```
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

The window start maximized and becomes non-maximized.

**3 test:**

In the following test, I inserted a sleep of 5 seconds. During this time, if I change the size of the window, when the maximize() after is called the window is correctly maximized:

```
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    System.out.println("Wait for maximize");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("Maximized");
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

**4 test:**

The same of before, but I recall the maximize after that the windows is correctly maximized.

```
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    System.out.println("Wait for maximize");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("Maximized");
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

In this test is showed the bug.

Because the behavior is not what is expected (from the documentation of the method):

```
   /**
     * Maximizes the current window if it is not already maximized
     */
    void maximize();
```

The steps:

1. When the window started is maximized.
2. During the first sleep, I changed the size of the window
3. At the end of the first sleep, the windows is correctly maximized.
4. I don't do anything during the second sleep
5. At the end of the 2 sleep, the window return with the same size that I changed in 2 step

Finally I made the the last test. Basically is the same of the last one, but in the 4 step, I rechanged the size of the window. In this case the window, at the end, is correclty maximized.

**EDIT**

About Chrome, you could do:

```
    Dimension dim= new Dimension(1280,860);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
```

Setting the desidered Dimension.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to reply me.

Comment: @IlzatAbdusamat Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, it is recomended to use the **`ChromeOptions`** Class to open Google Chrome in maximized mode as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```